# Find the scalar of a and b

Tags: vectors

Hi I need some help with vectors.

My u is (3,1,-1,5) and v is (0,2,1,-3). Find the scalar of a and b as au + bv = (3,-3,-3,11).

What i did was to add this two up, so I got a(3,1,-1,5) + b(0,2,1,-3) = (3,-3,-3,11)

Next I tried to do subtraction of equation one by one
3a+b = 3
a+2b=-3
-a+b=-3
5a-3b=11

I got 2a-3b = 2 and look at my answer it's the wrong equation.

Comment: Your first equation in $a$ and $b$ is wrong. The first coordinate in $v$ is 0, not 1, so the equation should be $3a + 0b = 3$.

Comment: The title of this post makes no sense.  A scalar and a vector are two different objects.  There is no "scalar" of a "vector."  What are you asking please?

Comment: You can equate each component separately. By inspection, $a=1, b=-2$

Comment: @DavidQuinn can kindly explain more in steps?

Comment: See the solution from juantheron below

Answer (score 1):

Given $\vec{u} = <3,1,-1,5>$ and $\vec{v} =<0,2,1,-3> $ and $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v} = <3,-3,-3,11>$

Now $$a<3,1,-1,5>+b<0,2,1,-3> = <3,-3,-3,11>$$

So $$<3a,a,-a,5a>+<0,2b,b,-3b> = <3,-3,-3,11>$$

So after Camparing, We get

$$3a=3$$ and $$a+2b = -3$$ and $$-a+b = -3$$ and $$5a-3b = 11$$

So $a=1$  and put into  $$a+2b=-3\Rightarrow b=-2$$

Comment: Thanks for the help but in my answer key, a=3 while b=-1

Comment: Put in second , third and fourth equation, If it satisfies or not